# which Asp.net page properties to work with ...? please find details below

Tags: asp.net

I am having an application where I am displaying an modal dialog if the page is getting loaded for first time but when i navigate to any other page within the web site then also the modal dialog get displayed what i need is modal diaolg should get displayed only for first time and not while navigating within web site. "Just one time display of modal dialog to user not again and again if user navigates within website"

The modal dialog is coming from javascript and i am using asp.net 3.5
and not using ispostback any suggestion or condition other than ispostback is needed

Is there any property of page which is true/false for first time the page is loaded and gets false/true when the user navigates to other page within website...?

any way/logic  to do it ...?

Thanks,

Nilesh

Comment: you could store a cookie and checking for it on every page load

Comment: pauli thanks for reply so quickly.. My question is if a user is on site www.abc.com/abc.aspx then the modal dialog should get displayed but when user click on any menu/submenu and gets naviagted to www.abc.com/pqr.aspx then dialog should not get displayed.. user is in same website .. but navigating to diffferent web page ...how can i use cookies ..any code sample.. or any other solution is also welcome... 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no property that will allow you to determine whether the pageis accessed for the first time or not. One way to handle this is to use a Session variable where you could store whether the user has already visited the first page.

Comment: @Nilesh, yes you can use session variable. In the `Page_Load` check if the session variable has been set and if not show the modal dialog and set the variable. To read/write session variable use the `Session` object. Example: `Session["isModalShown"] = true;`.

Comment: @Nilesh, here's a good article explaining how session works in ASP.NET: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExploringSession.aspx